# Locales and assets

Tags: assets, localization, multi-domain, multi-site

Is there a way to specify locale-specific asset paths so that uploaded images are only viewable on a per-locale basis, or would I have to set distinct assets (and ergo distinct fields) for each locale I wanted to provide uploads for?

For example, if am using locales to set a site A and a site B, can I have the same asset field declared but reference a different set of assets if they are logged in to site A rather than site B?

I've done some digging and testing and it looks like I can specify a locale in the general config, eg if following are declared in config (with `LOCALE` being defined in index.php based on locale :

```
'asset_path' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/resources/' . LOCALE . '/',
'asset_url' => 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/resources/' . LOCALE . '/',
```

However, despite this uploading files correctly (depending on context) these are still visible in the admin/control panel from other locales.

Is this at all possible? Working on a site with 6 locales that needs to keep assets separate and would rather not have to set multiple asset paths/file destinations and ergo multiple field types to achieve this.

Ta,

Cole

Answer (score 1):

I am not convienced that using Craft localization feature is a (good) solution to do multi-sites. But regarding you problem, did you try to add `craft.local` as part of a [Dynamic Subfolder Paths](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets-fields#dynamic-subfolder-paths) configuration. That could work for you.

Comment: Thanks Carl

I've tried this approach which works but the main problem is that assets for other locales remain visible in the assets modal, which we're trying to avoid

Comment: Did you have "Restrict uploads to a single folder?" set to true?

Comment: yes, but even removing shows everything contained within that folder, rather than anything specific to that locale

Comment: You could modify that plugin for you needs: [Asset Subfolder Access](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/AssetSubfolderAccess). Other than that I've no idea what you could do. If it was me, I wouldn't mis-use the localization feature to begin with.